# how do i get my all TFS shelve-sets in local using git-tf or git tfs?

Tags: git, tfs

Present i am merging a project TFS to GIT
(using git tfs tool), i am able to merge the project,
all change-sets converted to commits,
and it preserves the history.
[refer this](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md).
when i using below command

```
git tfs shelve-list -u=MyUserName
```

I am able to view all my shelve-sets from remote TFS.but i am not able to get all shelve-sets.
Similarly is there any way to convert shelve-sets to stashes and store locally.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a branch for each shelveset using (See https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/unshelve.md):

```
git tfs unshelve -u UserName MyShelvesetName MyBranch
```

That's not possible to unshelve them all (no one needed enough to contribute the development).

Note: Even if it's quite easy to add this feature in git-tfs ( here: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/src/GitTfs/Commands/Unshelve.cs#L43 ), and I will be pleased to merge the pull request if you do it...

Comment: i am not asking about un-shelving all shelve-sets, in git ,stash is equal to TFS shelve-set , my problem is how i get all TFS shelve-sets,form of stashes and it stores locally.

Comment: No, they are not equal. That's where you're wrong but I understand it's difficult to grasp for someone used to TFVC. In git, because branches are very cheap, it's a good practice to use it even for temporary development. And because shelvesets are named and stored on the server and could be accessed from other developers, they look more like branches. Keep stash for very temporary work (when rebasing). That's why git-tfs choose to unshelve in a branch. And you are not obliged to push them, just keep them local. And if you're not pleased, you could do a `git reset --soft` and do a stash.